# Thieves steal gold by melting it through a hole?

Tags: identify-this-movie

Which Movie is this? I remember the opening scene where the thieves make a hole under a bank vault and then heat the gold till it melts down into a trailer placed underneath. I cannot remember what happens after that.

I think at the end of the movie there is a Police Detective and another person in a boat watching a couple on the pier as they have the gold, the man picks the gold up and throws it in the water.

I have a hazy memory about this movie and cannot remind what it was called - I watch A LOT of movies, I might even be combining two movies together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are thinking of the movie [Stolen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1656186/), starring Nicolas Cage.

He plays a thief who gets caught, goes to prison, and does his time.  On getting out, his daughter is kidnapped by one of his former partners.  She is ransomed for the money that had been stolen in the caper that sent him to prison.  Since he destroyed the money before getting caught, he needs to come up with a new source of money.  He follows a plan he thought up in prison, namely to use a thermal lance to burn through the concrete floor below a large pile of gold bars, and melt the gold so it flows through the hole and cools in the water below.

And yes, at the end of the movie, Nicolas Cage is sitting at a picnic table with the female lead, debating keeping a large chunk of gold.  He is being watched by the main detective who is rooting for Nicolas to throw the gold into the Gulf of Mexico.  Nicolas then makes it appear as if he does indeed throw the gold into the water, but it turns out to be a ceramic pineapple that was sitting on the table... leaving the gold there on the table in the final shot.

Answer (score 3):

There was an episode of the original [Mission: Impossible S3E4](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0649329/) which did the gold through a whole bit. They drilled up through the floor ... Here's the part in the IMDB synopsis which tells about it:

> Meanwhile, IMF technical expert Barney Collier (Greg Morris) and muscle man Willy Armitage (Peter Lupus) carry out an elaborate plan to steal the mercenaries' gold. They drill up from a cave below into the vault where the gold is being held and use a complicated device to heat the vault to 2400 degrees, melting the gold and draining it through the floor, where they re-mold it back into ingots. After all the gold is sucked from the vault, the contraption seals the hole and repaints the floor, covering all traces of the theft. Barney and Willy quickly drive the gold out to an abandoned camp and bury it under a fireplace, getting out seconds before Rollin leads Krim and Karl to the 'other' gold. Krim then shoots Rollin, who pretends to die, and after Karl loads the gold into a false bottom in Jim's truck and sends him off, Krim kills Karl too.